# Проблема с рейтингом(Leaderboards) не записываются данные, сервис Google Play Games Services

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Всем привет, начал использовать Google Play Games Services, создал рейтинг, сделал 5 достижений, запустил в альфа-тестирование,  `Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, LEADERBOARD_ID, 1337);` так добавляю рейтинг, так запускаю `startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
        LEADERBOARD_ID), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);` , все у меня запускается показывает мол такой рейтинг есть и тд, но ничего не добавляет! авторизация через гуглАпи проходит. в чем проблема не пойму, может кто сталкивался и мне подскажет в чем там проблема может быть =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воообщем  для того что бы добавить рейтинг нужно сначала заработать хоть 1 достижение!